# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." from external client

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu, xampp

I have a small home server (Ubuntu+XAMPP) and 2 PHP scripts: `server.php` and `client.php`, which both communicate to each other via sockets.

When I run `server.php` / `client.php` on the same machine (`localhost`), it works fine. Also, when I run `server.php` on the server, and `client.php` on the same server but from other local PC (i.e. `local_server_ip`/`client.php`), all works fine as well.

However, when I run `server.php` on the server and `client.php` on the other PC on the same network (replacing `localhost` with `local_server_ip_addr` in the `client.php` script), it fails with the `actively refused connection` error.

All necessary ports are forwarded in the router. I guess it is kind of security block on XAMPP/Linux and can be eliminated by some configuration file. I replaced `Deny from all` in the `New XAMPP security concept` with `Allow from all` in `httpd-xamp.conf` file, but it still fails.

Any help would be much appreciated.

(PS: server/client scripts examples taken from http://i-novice.net/sokety-v-php/ )

**UPD: Have modified port 8080 (the one is dedicated for sockets in my system) to XXXXX. All works fine!**

Comment: Sounds like a firewall problem.

Comment: Firewall on Linux? How to configure it?

Comment: No clue, you'll have to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that this happens dependably, it actually implies that the machine exists however that it has no administrations listening on the predetermined port, or there is a firewall ceasing you.

In the event that it happens periodically - you utilized "now and then" - and retrying succeeds, it is likely in light of the fact that the server has a full 'overabundance'.

When you are holding up to be acknowledged on a listening attachment, you are put in a build-up. This overabundance is limited and short - estimations of 1, 2 or 3 are not bizarre - thus the OS may be not able to line your solicitation for the "acknowledge" to devour.

The build-up is a parameter on the listen capacity - all dialects and stages have essentially the same API in such manner, even the C# one. This parameter is frequently configurable in the event that you control the server, and is likely read from a few settings document or the registry. Research how to arrange your server.

In the event that you composed the server, you may have substantial preparing in the acknowledge of your attachment, and this can be better moved to a different specialist string so your acknowledge is constantly prepared to get associations. There are different structural engineering decisions you can investigate that alleviate lining up customers and handling them successively.

Notwithstanding whether you can build the server build-up, you do need retry rationale in your customer code to adapt to this issue - as even with a long build-up the server may be getting bunches of different demands on that port around then.

There is an uncommon probability where a NAT switch would give this blunder if its ports for mappings be depleted. I think we can toss this probability as a lot of a long shot however, since the switch has 64K concurrent associations with the same destination location/port before weariness.